# Can we use third party payment for subsription services outside the ios app?

Tags: ios, objective-c, in-app-purchase, applepay

I am developing an iOS application which allows users to register their services (includes apartments, homes, etc) to our platform through the application. This registration is payable and is recurring. 
There is one more option for the service providers to add their services to a featured list, which is non - recurring.
Please suggest if we can use third party payment gateways for this?

Answer (score 0):

No. Please check the appstore [guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#subscriptions). Specially read the **3.2.2 Unacceptable** point.

Comment: Why not, the OP said its can be apartment, homes,... (which are real services) so it's possible to use thirdparty payment method, only the one related to apple (app service) that is unacceptable

Comment: @Tj3n : In the question it was said _This registration is payable and is **recurring**._  So, Apple will force to use in app purchase. I faced the same problem once.

Comment: They said physical goods and service outside the app must use other than IAP...like applepay or other payment method, it should the same with subscription, and the Unacceptable point don't said anything about subscription must be IAP